# write() itertools.combinations() result to a file and avoid MemoryError

Tags: python, iterator, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to list all possible combinations of `10` elements in an array of `int`'s of `495` size.

The `arr` goes from `[0, 1, 2,..., 493, 494]`

My code:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
print(list(combinations_with_replacement(arr, 10))
```

Output: `MemoryError`

Is there a way I can save the result into a file without `MemoryError`? This way I can read the file line by line later on.

Comment: There are more than 2*10^20 such combinations, which would require more that 10^8 TB to store. What do you want to do with such data?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille exactly. Forget memory, Even if you assume each iteration takes 1 nanosecond (it definitely would take orders of magnitude more in Python) it would require [6896 years](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28494choose10%29+%C3%97+10%5E-9+seconds) to terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of an `iterator` is to build the data lazily, on-demand, when building a list of it, you asks to build all the data, don't, rather iterate on it.

```
with open("file.txt") as fic:
    for c in combinations_with_replacement(arr, 10):
        fic.write("".join(c) + "\n")
```

---

⚠️ From a comment

- 2.17615166796057920253 × 10^20  lines will take around `10^8` TB
- thousands years to end

Comment: Almost certainly this won't actually solve the OPs problem. The OP is trying to work with 498 choose 10 combinations, which is 2.17615166796057920253 × 10^20 ... so likely they will run out of disk space ... not to mention *time*. Even assuming it only takes 1 nanosecond for each iteration (it definitely takes much more) it would require almost 7 thousand years to complete.,..

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to iterate over the elements and print them, you can avoid creating a list with all elements:

```
for x in combinations_with_replacement(arr, 10):
    print(x)
```

This will print to `stdout` like you attempt in your code.  You can shell-redirect it to a file.